# MeetUp clone site

Tags: web-apps, social-networks

im searching the web for a Meetup like system. I'm trying to build a place very similar to them meetup format but something i can completely control edit etc.

the only things i found are:

Open source alternatives to meetup.com / Geolocation meetings enabler

https://bitbucket.org/SamuelMarks/giantpicnic

http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/

none of them look stable and good enough for what im searching for... so i have 2 question:

```
is there a better open source framework/site i can use?

if not does ruby on rails is a good language for building something like that?
```

Thanks any way.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Like list what features you require.

Comment: i am looking at doing something like this, but i would probably use something like angular.js on the front end a standard grails stack on the back end.